# How to go back to the original word from the output of Lucene's Porterstemmer (or any word stemmer)

Tags: nlp

I'm using the PorterStemmer with Lucene to stem words for some text analysis. I keep getting words like 'de' and 'en' that rank among the top. In order to remove them, I need to know what the original words were. Is there any way to find out?

Comment: Are you using Python? Also, why do you want to remove the high ranking words?

Comment: I'm using Lucene with java. I want to remove them because they appear as the top words in every cluster. So, I feel they are probably not adding any useful information to the model, just noise.

Comment: Are you removing stop words before stemming?

Comment: Yes.. but still these words.. 'de' and 'en' keep appearing. I can't reproduce them through feeding test words into the stemmer either.